# Remotely control MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: ios, appletv, remote-control, macbook-pro

The rMBP dropped the infrared receiver making Apple Remote useless with it. It's a shame, since Airplay + Apple TV + Apple Remote would have worked as a perfect combo.

So, while playing a movie with Quicktime / VLC and streaming it to the TV, how can I control the playing (pause, skip, rewind...) remotely? Is the iPhone or an iPad of any help? Is there any remote-control app?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to remote control the Apple TV? Or are you trying to remote control the MacBook Pro? (both will work!)

There's the [Remote app](http://www.apple.com/itunes/remote/) (*by Apple, not affiliated*) which can control the Apple TV, and there are probably lots of 'VLC Remote' apps if you are trying to control VLC itself.

- VLC Remote Free for iOS [here](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/vlc-remote-free/id299344206?mt=8)
- VLC Remote (paid) for iOS [here](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/vlc-remote/id297244048?mt=8)

These work directly with the VLC client and allow for the full control experience - media selection, play, pause, rewind, forward etc.

Answer (score 2):

The remote app for iPhone will let you control any Mac or PC running iTunes. Remember, though, it controls iTunes, not the whole Mac. There is also a Keynote Remote app that will supposedly let you remote control that app, but I've not tried it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Rowmote](http://regularrateandrhythm.com/apps/rowmote-pro/), [Hippo Remote](http://hipporemote.com). They will let you control any mac and application for media purposes or just for using a wireless keyboard and mouse from your iOS device.